# C++ Template Array class: Error generation depends on whether it inherits an interface or not

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, interface

Sorry for the vague title - I didn't know how to shortly describe my question. I have been playing around with the composite design pattern and ran into the following situation. Say I have an interface

```
class interface
{
public:
   virtual ~interface() { }
   virtual void methodA(const uint8_t* ptr) = 0;
};
```

And say I have a template class that adheres to this interface (this is just a simple example I know it doesn't make much sense).

```
template <typename T>
class customArray
{
public:
   void methodA(const uint8_t* ptr)
   {
      if (m_data.size())
         m_data[0].methodA(ptr);
   }

   int methodB(uint8_t* ptr)
   {
      if (m_data.size())
         return m_data[0].methodB(ptr);

      return 0;
   }

   void push_back(const T& elm)
   {
      m_data.push_back(elm);
   }

private:
   std::vector<T> m_data;
};
```

Note that the template class does not inherit the interface. Now if I define some simple class

```
class customPrimitive
{
public:
   int methodB(uint8_t* ptr)
   {
      (void)ptr;
      return -1337;
   }
};
```

And use it like so

```
customArray<customPrimitive> arr;
arr.push_back(customPrimitive());
printf("Got %i\n", arr.methodB(NULL)); // Prints -1337
// arr.methodA(NULL); This will make build fail
```

Obviously the build should fail if I try to call methodA. But why doesn't it fail when I avoid calling it ?

Furthermore, why does the build fail if I make the array inherit the interface ? In this case it happens regardless of whether I call the method or not.

If anyone could provide me with some insight that would much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not calling it, the compiler is optimizing `customArray.methodA` away.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was confused because other places I use the template with other classes and call methodA. But for the particular instance of customArray<customPrimitive> the method would be optimized away. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're interface class has a pure virtual method "methodA". This force all his inheritors to implement this method, and if they didn't, build fails. Thats the main idea of interface / abstract classes.